# timePicker AM and PM swapped and brings a negative minute number

Tags: c#, android, timepicker

I have setup the `timePicker` as `24 hour` mode, however if the time is currently `16:05` and I choose `16:10` from the `timePicker`, it says `12 hours and 5 minutes` instead of `5 minutes`. How can I easily swap the `AM` and `PM`?

In addition if I choose the same `hour` with `minutes` being smaller than `current minutes`, I will have an output such as `12 hours and -4 minutes` .

Code:

```
public void onClickAlarmOn(View v) {

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    TimePicker alarm_time_picker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker); //initializing timePicker before using it //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25485768/why-does-my-app-keep-crashing-when-i-try-to-insert-a-date-and-time-picker
    int hour = alarm_time_picker.getCurrentHour(); //get selected hour
    int minute = alarm_time_picker.getCurrentMinute(); //get selected minute

    int hour_now = c.get(Calendar.HOUR); //get system's hour
    int minute_now = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE); //get system's minute

    int hour_result = hour - hour_now; //subtract the time selected by time.now of system
    int minute_result = minute - minute_now;

    String hour_result_string = String.valueOf(hour_result); //convert to string to display
    String minute_result_string = String.valueOf(minute_result);

    setToast_result("Alarm set to " + hour_result_string + " hours " + minute_result_string + " minutes");
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: is it c# or java? it's can't be both, can it?

Comment: @user1666620 Sorry confused it for a second, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the 24-hour clock, you want to get `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY` from your `Calendar` instance, instead of `Calendar.HOUR`, which is based on the 12-hour clock.

```
int hour_now = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
```